# Extract the equalities / inequalities from the text (linear programming, optimization)

Tags: inequality, optimization, linear-programming, word-problem, operations-research

> "My garden" is a company which produces two kind of fertilisers and
>   sells these: The first kind "Perfect Grass" and the second kind "Super
>   Grass". In order to produce both kinds, you respectively need the 3
>   resources $M_1, M_2, M_3$ in different quantities. To produce
>   $1\text{kg}$ "Perfect Grass", you need $2\text{kg}$ of $M_1$,
>   $1\text{kg}$ of $M_2$ and $2\text{kg}$ of $M_3$. To produce
>   $1\text{kg}$ "Super Grass", you need $3\text{kg}$ of $M_1$,
>   $2\text{kg}$ of $M_2$ and $1\text{kg}$ of $M_3$. During the next week,
>   the company can at most handle $1500\text{kg}$ of the resource $M_1$,
>   $1200\text{kg}$ of $M_2$ and $1300\text{kg}$ of $M_3$. The company
>   achieves a profit of $5 €$ per $\text{kg}$ of "Perfect Grass" and $8€$
>   per $1\text{kg}$ of "Super Grass". For the next week, the company has
>   already received an order of $100\text{kg}$ of the kind "Perfect
>   Grass" and affirmed the delivery.
>
> How much kilogram of each kind of fertilisers should the company
>   produce in the next week to achieve maximum profit? It's presumed that
>   the company will sell the produced quantity entirely. Solve this task
>   by using simplex algorithm.
>
> *Hint: Firstly solve this task without respecting the advance order and
>   optimize afterwards, if necessary.*

I only want know the correct inequalities / equalities. I can solve the rest of the task on my own. But if this part is wrong, everything will be wrong... So here is what I got from the text:

Perfect Grass: $x_1 = 2m_1+m_2+2m_3$

Super Grass: $x_2 = 3m_1+2m_2+m_3$

$m_1 \leq 1500, m_2 \leq 1200, m_3 \leq 1300$

The objective function is $P=5y_1+8y_2$

---

Is it alright like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my view it is wrong. You have three resource constraints ($M_1, M_2, M_3$).

First I define the variables.

$x=$Amount of Perfect Grass in kg.

$y=$Amount of Super Grass in kg.

$m_i$=Amount of resource $i$ in kg.

$\color{olive}{\text{contraints}}$

$m_1=2x+3y\leq 1500 \qquad (M_1)$

$m_2=x+2y\leq 1200 \qquad (M_2)$

$m_3=2x+y\leq 1300\qquad (M_3)$

$x\geq 100$

This constraints are not equivalent to your constraints. Suppose the solution is $(x,y)=(500,100)$. Then $m_1=2\cdot 500+3\cdot 100=1300,m_2=700,m_3=1100$. This doesn´t satisfy for instance your equality for the amount of Perfect Grass:

$500\neq 2\cdot 1300+200+2\cdot 1100$

$\color{olive}{\text{obejective function}}$

$\texttt{max} \ \ 5x+8y$

$\color{olive}{\text{non-negativity condition}}$

$x,y\geq 0$

Comment: Oh thank you very much for correction, I was scared no one will answer :) I have only one more question.  Where is this constraint for the advance order ($100 \text{kg }$ "Perfect Grass") ? Is it just  your $x \geq 100$ ?

Comment: @tenepolis You are welcome. Yes, because you already know you have to produce at least 100 kg of Perfect Grass.